# Recommendation system design

Tags: recommendation-engine

I am currently working on a research in which I try to predict people's IQ.
This is how the research goes, on day 1 participants take IQ test. At regular intervals of 2 weeks they continue to take the test (with different questions maybe) for 6 months.

Given this information (or dataset) how does one go about designing a recommendation system.
I imagine it something like this

> IQvalue --input--> [ Recommendation Engine ] --spits out--> probable IQ value (after 6 months)

My actual research is not on IQ at all. I just made this example up.
Kindly suggest if I am going in the right direction at all? Are there any algorithms that do something similar?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: please consider adding a comment before down voting.

Comment: So you want to know how to grade them? Why don't you do some googling to see how the current IQ tests are graded?

Comment: I do not want to know how they are graded. My research is not about IQ tests at all. I'm talking about a recommendation system.

Comment: And I downvoted because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The tag [recommendation-engine](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/recommendation-engine/info) didn't say it is about programming so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

For case 1, you only have the time-related IQ values, I suggest you consider the **time series analysis** methods. Your target is to predict how the IQ change with time. My suggestion for this solution is the **statsmodels** library. Its github address is as follows:
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels .
This tool is written in python and easy to use. It contains many generally used tsa models, such as ARIMA.

For case 2, if you also have the features of people, for instance, the answers in the QA test, ages, gender, education, etc., I suggest you consider use a machine learning methods to predict the IQs. You may consider the random forest or gradient boost to solve this problem. I suggest you use the tools such as Scikit-learn or xgboost.

For case 3, you can model it as a recommender system problem. Suppose user-test people, item-IQ, rating-IQ value, you can construct a user-item matrix. After that, you can use RS methods, such as matrix factorization or memory-based methods to predict the IQ values.

In my opinion, the first two means may be better for your case.